# Filling nulls with last not null value in SQL Server on Postal Codes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `PostalCodes` (with one column with values from 00-00 to 99-999) and `Customers` (which has, beside all the customer's data, a postal code and ID of employee which is serving the customer).

So these two I am simply joining via postal code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    KP.postal,
    K.IDemp
FROM
    PostalCodes KP 
LEFT JOIN
    [Customers] K ON K.postal = KP.postal
```

and I'm getting this:

```
| postal | IDemp |
+--------+-------+
| 00-000 | NULL  |
| 00-001 | NULL  |
| 00-001 | 12PH  |
| 00-002 | NULL  |
| 00-003 | NULL  |
| 00-004 | NULL  |
| 00-004 | 10PH  |
| 00-005 | NULL  |
| ...    | ...   |
```

So as you can see not all postal codes are used in the `Customers` table, but for my aim I need all postal codes assigned to some employee to created something like "area of service", so to do that I want to fill null values with last not null value to get something like this:

```
| postal | IDemp |
+--------+-------+
| 00-000 | NULL  |
| 00-001 | 12PH  |
| 00-002 | 12PH  |
| 00-003 | 12PH  |
| 00-004 | 10PH  |
| 00-005 | 10PH  |
| ...    | ...   |
```

I was trying to use `LAG()` function, but it was not working (or at least I don't know how use it properly)

```
LAG(K.IDemp) OVER (ORDER BY KP.postal)
```

I found few similar questions already, but could not come up how to use their answers to my case.

Comment: "last not null" what does this mean? There is no sorting here

Comment: Something like this  cross apply (select top 1 postal from PostalCodes KP  where K.postal =< KP.postal order by KP.postal) as emp

Comment: Which version of sql server? Azure SQL Edge supports IGNORE NULLS with LAST_VALUE()...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correlated sub-query might work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    KP.postal,
    (SELECT TOP 1 K.IDemp 
     FROM [Customers] K
     WHERE K.postal <= KP.postal
     AND K.IDemp Is Not Null
     ORDER BY K.postal DESC) As IDemp
FROM
    PostalCodes KP
```

Comment: I guess this is similar to what I propose above but cross apply is then faster. Could still be null if  the first one is null.  So should look in both direction and sort by the diff to the target postal

Comment: I guess it would depend on the indexes, but I'd expect the correlated sub-query and a `CROSS APPLY` to produce very similar plans.

Comment: Possibly, I have had bad experiences in the past but of course SQL server has evolved . There were a time when re-writing old nested code to cross apply was a sure success but of course the cases that worked fine I would never have seen.

Comment: Add `AND K.IDemp IS NOT NULL` to the subquery in order to neglect nulls.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's not clear from the question, but I would assume that the `IDemp` column in the `Customers` table is `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Look at the result of OP's query. The postal code 00-001 results in two rows, one with the IDemp '12PH' one with IDemp NULL. So the NULL cannot stem from the outer join, but must exist in the customers table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't support the ignore nulls option on `LAG` (yet), but you can get around this by creating a binary value from the column you want to order by, and the column you want to retrieve and calling `MAX` which does ignore nulls. A full working solution would be:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;

CREATE TABLE #T (Postal VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, IDemp VARCHAR(4) NULL);
INSERT #T (Postal, IDemp)
VALUES
    ('00-000', NULL),
    ('00-001', '12PH'),
    ('00-002', NULL),
    ('00-003', NULL),
    ('00-004', '10PH'),
    ('00-005', NULL);


SELECT  *,
        LastNonNull = CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), 
                            SUBSTRING(
                                MAX(CONVERT(BINARY(6), Postal) + CONVERT(BINARY(4), IDemp)) 
                                    OVER(ORDER BY Postal), 7,4))
FROM    #T;
```

It might help explain if this is broken down a bit and we look at the results of this:

```
SELECT  *,
        BinaryValue = CONVERT(BINARY(6), Postal) + CONVERT(BINARY(4), IDemp)
FROM    #T
```

| Postal | IDemp | BinaryValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00-000 | NULL | NULL |
| 00-001 | 12PH | 0x30302D30303131325048 |
| 00-002 | NULL | NULL |
| 00-003 | NULL | NULL |
| 00-004 | 10PH | 0x30302D30303431305048 |
| 00-005 | NULL | NULL |

Since concatenating null value yields a null value, you only get a value where it is not null. You can then take advantage of binary sorting (left to right) and get the maximum value of this binary within a windowed function, that is the part: `MAX(...) OVER(ORDER BY Postal)`.

This removes all the NULL values (since `MAX` ignores `NULL`) apart from the first row, since there is no previous non null value and gives data as follows:

| Postal | IDemp | MaxBinaryValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00-000 | NULL | NULL |
| 00-001 | 12PH | 0x30302D30303131325048 |
| 00-002 | NULL | 0x30302D30303131325048 |
| 00-003 | NULL | 0x30302D30303131325048 |
| 00-004 | 10PH | 0x30302D30303431305048 |
| 00-005 | NULL | 0x30302D30303431305048 |

It is then just a case of extracting the portion of the binary you are interested in (characters 7-10) and converting back to varchar using `SUBSTRING` and `CONVERT`